# Как выполнить умножение и указать результат в input?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!

У меня есть два `<input>`-а. В один я ввожу цифру, во втором должен показывается результат умножения или деления этой цифры на заранее заданное число.

Как можно организовать динамический пересчёт прямо во время набора текста, без нажатия на какие-либо GUI-кнопки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var argument = $('input[name="argument"]')
      , result = $('input[name="result"]')
      , multiplier = 4;
    argument.on('input', function() {
      result.val($(this).val() * multiplier);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="argument"/>
<input type="number" name="result"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на чистом JavaScript:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("inpt");
const inputResult = document.getElementById("res");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    inputResult.value = input.value * 4;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="argument"/ id="inpt">
<input type="number" id="res" name="result"/>
```

Вариант с JQuery:

```js
$('#inpt').on('keyup', () => {
  $('#res').val($('#inpt').val() * 4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" name="argument" id="inpt">
<input type="number" id="res" name="result" />
```